# a folder where 2 android applications can both read and write?

Tags: android, file, xamarin

currently we're porting 2 applications (from Windows), both programs do different tasks and is on separate programs because it is designed this way, one program will do the UDP communication basically a daemon and it will translate those UDP packets to json and it will write to a file, the other program will read to that file and it will display to the user. But on the Android file system it seems impossible, I have to deal with storage permissions and basically I can't find a solution, I need a folder in Android that allows reading and writing of files from 2 programs simultaneously without worrying about permissions.

I have tried all the folders in `Android.OS.Environment` and seems like there's no folder that allows such thing, I'm working on Android Q and I can't even create a file on storage/emulated/0, is there any way for this to happen?

Comment: In the classic way you can create files in public Documents directory or subfolders of them. The other app lets the user choose the folder or file using SAF.

Comment: But first app can also use a ContentProvider to serve the file to the second app.

Comment: `allows reading and writing of files from 2 programs simultaneously ` Simultanously is probably asked too much. Investigate.

Comment: @blackapps Documents folder seems to work for now

Comment: @Alizer Seems that you have solved your problem now?